# Oracle installation and login errors

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I installed oracle 11g on my laptop and I am having two problems, I can not login to sqlplus it wants a password and login which I do not have. Is there any default user name and password I can use?
The other problem is that I can not connect to my localhost its saying

> Enterprise Manager is not able to connect to the database instance. The state of the components are listed below

```
Database Instance
Host    
Port    
SID 
Oracle Home
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: You get to set a password on install, I thought it was even mandatory in the modern installers...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log in as `sysdba`, make sure you are connected as the Oracle user (whichever one you chose), and type:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

No password required, as long as you're the right user.

To be able to connect to the database, it must be started, and the listener service must also be started. To check listener status:

```
$ lsnrctl status
```

To start/stop it, replace `status` by `start` or `stop`. If you installed named listeners, append the listener name to the `lsnrctl` commands above (i.e. put the listener name *after* the status/start/stop command).

Comment: i managed to log into sqlplus but the second command how to i run it??im using windows cmd.

Comment: Make sure the path to Oracle binary files is in your path, and just run those commands from cmd.exe. Not sure what the installation layout is on windows, but the exes are probably in `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`, or something like that.

Comment: its bringing something,what is a named listener?

Comment: See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96580/listener.htm) - it's just a listener with a name different from the default name (LISTENER).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you installed oracle on Windows:
If you have been able to connect to the database using `sqlplus / as sysdba` then your listener is up and you are connecting on the box where oracle is installed. If you installed oracle on windows, a user group called ora_dba will be created and your windows account willl be in that group. This grants you the sysdba role and allows you to log on to the database using `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

During istallation of the database you must have been prompted to enter a password for at least SYS and SYSTEM unlocked accounts.

To start enterprise manager try the command line:

`emctl start dbconsole`

or start the windows services snap in and check to see if the service OracleDBConsoleSID (SID is the ORACLE_SID for your database) is running. If not start it. When the service starts successfully, try running EM again.